# Why is my web site certificate not recognized on iphone devices only?

Tags: ssl-certificate, iphone, ssl-certificate-errors

I have a web site that I manage at [myradental.com](https://myradental.com) . I have installed SSL certificate over cpanel. The pages opens with no problem on any browsers on PC, android devices and etc. But when I try to open the page using iPhone it says

[image: iPhone screenshot]

"the web page might be impersonating...".

I have deleted current CSR, re-created a new one, associated it with the SSL certificate but nothing has changed. First, I want to figure out that this is a device/platform based problem or I did something wrong in the configuration in cPanel. If there was a problem with my configuration the web site would never open in any platform.

Can someone clarify things please?

Comment: https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=myradental.com Your certificate is revoked

Comment: How come does it work with no error on PC?

Comment: It's now 100% down for everyone.

Comment: I have removed SSL certificate to install it again. But now, I cannot find my private key. The documentation at GoDaddy says that the private key could be found in `.httpd.conf` or `apache2.conf`. Since it is a shared hosting, I have no access to those files

Answer (score 0):

I am going to tell what I have done to make it.

1. I uninstalled the certificate from server.
2. I have deleted all the related CSR's and private keys, which is not needed, just for clear the lists.
3. I created a private key first.
4. Then I created a CSR relating the private key.
5. I uploaded the certificate from my computer and installed.
6. I checked ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=myradental.com

Now it shows a big green A for the site. But I must be sure if iPhone still shows "impersonating" error.

Comment: A quick check from my iPhone shows no error.

Comment: Thanks @Massimo, Grazie mille!